# How to auto-crop a barrel-distorted image using ImageMagick?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, crop, photos, distortion

Using ImageMagick's `convert` to barrel-distort a photo to correct a strongly visible pincushion distortion, I provide positive a, b or c values (from a database for my lens + focal length). This results in an image that is corrected, has the original width and height, but includes a non-rectangular, bent/distorted border, as the image is corrected towards its center. Simplified example:

```
convert rose: -virtual-pixel black -distort Barrel '+0.0 +0.1 +0.0' out.png
```

How can I automatically crop the black, bent border to the largest possible rectangle in the original aspect ratio within the rose?

[image]

The ImageMagick website says, that a parameter "d" is automatically calculated, that could do this (resulting in linear distortion effectively zooming into the image and pushing the bent border right outside the image bounds), but the imagemagick-calculated value seems to aim for something different (v6.6.9 on ubuntu 12.04). If I guess and manually specify a "d", I can get the intended result:

```
convert rose: -virtual-pixel black -distort Barrel '+0.0 +0.1 +0.0 +0.6' out.png
```

The given formular a+b+c+d=1 does not seem to be a proper d for my cropping case. Also, d seems to depend on the aspect ratio of the image and not only on a/b/c. How do I make ImageMagick crop the image, or, how to I calculate a proper d?

**Update**

I found Fred's ImageMagick script `innercrop` (http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/innercrop/index.php) that does a bit what I need, but has drawbacks and is no solution for me. It asumes arbitrary outer areas, so it takes long to find the cropping rectangle. It does not work within Unix pipes, and it does not keep the original aspect ratio.

**Update 2**

Contemplating on the problem makes me think that calculating a "d" is not the solution, as changing d introduces more or less bending and seems to do more than just zoom. The d=1-(a+b+c) that is calculated by imagemagick results in the bent image touching the upper/lower bounds (for landscape images) or the left/right bounds (for portrait images). So I *think* the proper solution would be to calculate where one of the new 4 corners will be given a/b/c/d, and then crop to those new corners.

Comment: Since my first comment from last night seems to have disappeared, let me repeat it: Can you please provide a sample image that you want to process, as well as the values for `a`, `b` and `c` which are valid for your camera/lens/zoom combo?

Comment: I sure could, but I do not understand how that adds anything to this problem. The `rose:` is as good as any picture and shows the issue perfectly, as does your checkers - what happens to the motiv is not the issue here. Before I find a place for uploads, you could use the 3 distortions '0.1 0 0', '0 0.1 0' and '0 0 0.1' on the rose. Now you have simulated different (simplified) distortions and have different bent, black borders. The question is, what d in each case would had the black area "zoomed away" and why.

Answer (score 0):

The way ***I*** understand the docs, you do not use commas to separate the parameters for the barrel-distort operator.

Here is an example image, alongside the output of the two commands you gave:

```
convert o.png -virtual-pixel black -distort Barrel '+0.0 +0.1 +0.0' out0.png
convert o.png -virtual-pixel black -distort Barrel '+0.0 +0.1 +0.0 +0.6' out1.png
```

[image] [image] [image]

I created the example image in order to better visualize what you possibly want to achieve.

However, I do not see the point you stated about the automatically calculated parameter *'d'*, and I do not see the effect you stated about using *'d=+0.6'*...

I'm not sure I understand your wanted result correctly, so I'm assuming you want the area marked by the yellow rectangle cropped.

The image on the left is `out0.png` as created by the first command above. 
In order to guess the required coordinates, we have to determine the image dimensions first:

```
identify out0.png
 out0.png PNG 700x700 700x700+0+0 8-bit sRGB 36KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

The image in the center is marked up with the white rectangle. The rectangle is there so you can look at it and tell me if that is the region you want cropped. The image on the right is the cropped image (without scaling it back to the original size).

[image] [image] [image]

***Is this what you want?*** If yes, I can possibly update the answer in order to automatically determine the required coordinates of the cropping. (For now I've done it based on guessing.)

---

### Update

I think you may have mis-understood the purpose of the barrel-distortion operation. It is meant for ***correcting*** a barrel (slight) distortion, as is produced by camera lenses. The 3 parameters `a`, `b` and `c` to be used for any specific combination of camera, lens and current zoom could possibly be stated in your photo's EXIF data. The formula were `a+b+c+d = 1` is meant to be used when the new, distortion-corrected image should have the same dimensions as the original (distorted) image.

So to imitate the barrel-correction, we should probably use the second image from the last row above as our input:

```
convert out3.png -virtual-pixel gray -distort barrel '0 -0.2 0' corrected.png
```

Result:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. Yes, I do use this for correcting lens distorion in photos. And I do have proper a, b and c values from a database for my lens for a given focal length, but I do not have d. Using comma or not seems not to make a difference, but let's switch to the offical non-comma format. Like in your second example, I want to get rid of the outer black area while keeping as much red as possible. In the past, I used `fulla` from the hugin package to correct the image, which calculates d itself and/or manages to crop the image automatically.

Comment: And: In my tests, using `-distort barrel` always creates a same width/height as the original. A negative/positive d results in a linear zoom in/out on the final result, pushing the bent border just outside the cropping area if the right value is used. And the image usually is 3:2/2:3 aspect ratio, not 1:1. Finally, I do not care if the result is obtained by cropping or zooming in, as long as original aspect ratio is kept.

Comment: About the d=-0.6: this value only works for the rose as it depends on the aspect ratio. Also it is just a guess, and may be more accurate with -0.599 or 0.601 or ...